# Codeigniter foreach loop row to insert into table

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a form in front-end, I am trying to fetch value into hidden input element and then trying to insert into table. But it's not working, I am getting an error of undefined variable `user_id_ins` I am fetching value into hidden input element from `get_autocomplete` function.

Can you guys help me with achieving this?

Controller

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class AddMeeting extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->model('meetinginsert');
    }

    function index() {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('organisationName', 'Organisation name', 'required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            $this->load->view('addmeeting');
        } else {

        $data = array(
            'organisation_name' => $this->input->post('organisationName'),
            'user_id' => $this->input->post('user_id')
        );

        $this->meetinginsert->meeting_insert($data);
        $data['message'] = 'Meeting added';
        $this->load->view('addmeeting', $data);
        }
    }

    function get_autocomplete() {
        if(isset($_GET['term'])) {
            $result = $this->meetinginsert->search_user($_GET['term']);
            if(count($result) > 0) {
                foreach($result as $row) {
                    $user_id_ins = $row->id;
                    $arr_result[] = $row->first_name . " " . $row->last_name;
                    echo json_encode($arr_result);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

View

```
<input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="<?php echo $user_id_ins; ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's `$arr_result` what you're feeding into the view, the error is because `$user_id_ins` is not contained in `$arr_result` and thus not being passed on to the view.

`$arr_result`, the way you have it now, is only a one dimensional array in which every element is just the concatenation of name and last name. What you need is to pass both arguments such as:

```
$arr_result[] = (user_id_ins => $user_id, fullname => $row->first_name . " " . $row->last_name);
```

Then you can access both fields in the view by calling `$user_id_ins` and `$fullname` (or whatever name you're willing to use)

Comment: I did what you said but now I am getting 500 internal server error because of model, `function search_user($title) {
  $this->db->like('first_name', $title, 'both');
  $this->db->order_by('first_name', 'ASC');
  $this->db->limit(10);
  return $this->db->get('users')->result();
 }` how can I change this model according to your way?